martinize issue
PS C:\Users\MALINE\Desktop\martini> python martinize.py -f polypropylene.pdb -o output.pdb

INFO       MARTINIZE, script version 2.6
INFO       If you use this script please cite:
INFO       de Jong et al., J. Chem. Theory Comput., 2013, DOI:10.1021/ct300646g
INFO       Chain termini will be charged
INFO       Residues at chain brakes will not be charged
INFO       The martini22 forcefield will be used.
INFO       Local elastic bonds will be used for extended regions.
INFO       Read input structure from file.
INFO       Input structure is a PDB file.
INFO       Found 1 chains:
INFO          1:   A (Unknown), 482 atoms in 1 residues.
INFO       Removing HETATM chain A consisting of 1 residues.
INFO       Total size of the system: 0 residues.
WARNING    No secondary structure or determination method speficied. Protein chains will be set to 'COIL'.
INFO       (Average) Secondary structure has been determined (see head of .itp-file).
INFO       Written 0 ITP file
INFO       Output contains 0 molecules:
INFO       Written topology files
INFO       Note: Cysteine bonds are 0.24 nm constraints, instead of the published 0.39nm/5000kJ/mol.

        There you are. One MARTINI. Shaken, not stirred.


Why don't you get out of that wet coat and into a dry martini?
                                                               --Robert Benchley

my output shows 0 molecules. why?

The relevant section of the output is here:
INFO       Found 1 chains: INFO          1:   A (Unknown), 482 atoms in 1 residues. INFO       Removing HETATM chain A consisting of 1 residues. 
It finds only 1 chain/residue for which it doesn't recognize any of the atoms (all are seemingly marked HETATM) and so it removes that residue, leaving you with nothing left. Its possible Martini has a setting to let you retain heteroatoms or you may just be able to clean up your input if you believe some things are being mislabeled as heteroatoms.

Possibly related question/answer on BioInformatics SE

Why dos this question have the Python tag? Also please make the title of your question more specific and clear.
